# Why can't meson determine the size of time_t if running in a container with a tmpfs?

Tags: c, docker, meson-build

Inspired by systemd's `meson.build` file, I have created the following file:

```
project('test','c')
cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
cc.sizeof('time_t', prefix : '#include <sys/time.h>')
```

If I run this in a container via `docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04 bash` and install meson via `apt update && apt install -y meson gcc`, this works as expected, returning:

> Checking for size of "time_t": 8

However, add the flag `--tmpfs /tmp` to `docker run`, the result is this:

> Checking for size of "time_t": -1

Why does this happen? Does meson maybe create temporary executables in `/tmp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing the mount options of `/tmp` in both containers, it turned out to be very simple: docker does seem to set `noexec` by default, that's why you have to explicitly set the `exec` flag:

```
--tmpfs /tmp:rw,nosuid,nodev,exec
```

Comment: Or, you can set `TMPDIR` environment variable to another place with exec enabled.  Meson logs many incidentes in `builddir/meson-logs/meson-log.txt`.